# ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) ASC LIMIT 1; IN MYSQL DOESN'T SHOW FIRST ITEM

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, limit

I'm trying to show the smallest city in a list and its length. It also has to be the first one alphabetically in case there is more then 1 with the same length, but whenever I use the code below, I receive the second one in the list.

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) ASC LIMIT 1;
```

When I use

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

instead of just

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) ASC LIMIT 1;
```

I get the correct answser. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please show us an example data and expected output

Comment: we can use multiple expressions in an ORDER BY clause, e.g. `ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(city) ASC, city ASC  LIMIT 1`

Comment: `OFFSET 1` means show the second row in the reault set, OFFSET is Zero based

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY)` only orders by the length of the city name.  Cities with the same length are in an arbitrary ordering.

If you want to then order by the city alphabetically, then use:

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY), CITY
```